# How to deal with eval nil issues in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, elasticsearch, amazon-s3, eval, ruby-on-rails-5

I am facing a pretty nasty error in a production environment that caused a bit of confusion. I increased logging on production to narrow down the issue and was now able to reproduce it on our local environment. So setup wises we are running on Rails 5, on a Ubuntu machine. The application uses ElasticSearch 5.4, and we are storing images on Amazon S3.

**Process:** A user can upload images. There is a User Index in Elasticsearch that also stores information to the related Photo model.

**The issue** is that once a user uploads a photo, it sometimes comes to an error on an index page or detailed user page where photos are in one way or another accessed. And the results to be displayed are not read from a database but Elasticsearch.

**Workaround** (which isn't one). Once the index is getting reimported the error doesn't occur any longer - which initially led me to believe that it has something to do with ElasticSearch.

**User Model**

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
      include UserSearchable

  extend FriendlyId
  require "redis"
  friendly_id :slug_candidates, use: :slugged

  has_many :photos

  after_update { self.photos.each(&:touch) }

  ...
```

end

**User Searchable Concern**

module UserSearchable
      extend ActiveSupport::Concern

```
  included do
    include Elasticsearch::Model
    include Elasticsearch::Model::Callbacks

    index_name Rails.application.class.parent_name.underscore
    document_type self.name.downcase

    settings index: { number_of_shards: 1 } do
      mapping dynamic: false do
        indexes :description, analyzer: 'english'
        indexes :tagline, analyzer: 'english'
        indexes :username
        ...
      end
    end

    after_touch() { __elasticsearch__.index_document }

    def as_indexed_json(_options = {})
      self.as_json(
          except: [:email, :lat, :lng, :status, :termsofuse, :v_code],
          include: {
              photos: { only: [:name, :caption, :active, :image_data, :downloadable, :uploader_id, :public] },
      ).merge(
          location: {lat: lat.to_f, lon: lng.to_f},
          age: birthday.nil? ? 18 : ((Date.today - birthday.to_date) / 365.25).floor
      )
    end

    def home_search(searcher, order = nil, how_many = nil)
      how_many = 400 unless how_many.is_a?(Integer)
      order = 1 unless order.is_a?(Integer)

      if self.radius < 30
        use_radius = 30
      else
        use_radius = self.radius
      end

      search_definition = Jbuilder.encode do |json|
        json.sort do
          if order == 1
            json.array! [{'_geo_distance' => { :location => {:lat => lat, :lon => lng} }}, '_score']
          else
            json.array! ['_score', {'_geo_distance' => { :location => {:lat => lat, :lon => lng} }}]
          end
        end
        json.query do
          json.bool do
            json.filter do
              json.bool do
                json.must do
                  json.array! [:geo_distance => { :distance => use_radius, :unit => "mi", :location => {:lat => self.lat, :lon => self.lng}, :boost => 5.0}]
                end
                ...
                unless searcher.id.nil?
                  json.must_not do
                    json.array! [ {:term => { 'id' => self.id }} ]
                  end
                end
              end
            end
            ...
          end
        end
        # json.size how_many
      end


      self.class.__elasticsearch__.search(search_definition)
    end
  end
end
```

**Photo Model**

```
class Photo < ApplicationRecord
  include ImageUploader[:image]
  include ActiveModel::Validations

  acts_as_taggable

  before_create :set_name

  belongs_to :user, touch: true

  after_update { self.user(&:touch) }

  private

    def set_name
      self.name = "Photo"
    end
end
```

**Tests of issue in console:**

Here, and this is **key** to the problem. If I eval for the photo sometimes it is nil, and sometimes it is not! And I cannot figure out why? If I run this command lets say 10 times on console, it is nil 2 out of 10 times. And that is when the production system is thrown off its track and the user is presented with an error. As the system is intranet and new we actually show exceptions to users (so do not be alarmed by bad exception handling - users don't say a thing if you don't make it clear ;) )

```
>> eval(user.photos.sample.image_data)[:small][:id]
=> "photo/47/image/small-2cd0928d02826f0614086a01ee97ef32.jpg"
>> eval(user.photos.sample.image_data)[:small][:id]
!! #<NoMethodError: undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass>
```

*Additional trace:*

```
    >> Settings.s3 + eval(user.photos.sample.image_data)[:small][:id]
    !! #<NoMethodError: undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass>
    >> eval(user.photos.sample.image_data)[:small][:id]
    => "photo/47/image/small-2cd0928d02826f0614086a01ee97ef32.jpg"
    >> eval(user.photos.sample.image_data)[:small][:id]
    => "photo/47/image/small-2cd0928d02826f0614086a01ee97ef32.jpg"
    >> eval(user.photos.sample.image_data)[:small][:id]
    => "photo/47/image/small-2cd0928d02826f0614086a01ee97ef32.jpg"
    >> eval(user.photos.sample.image_data)[:small][:id]
    => "photo/47/image/small-2cd0928d02826f0614086a01ee97ef32.jpg"
    >> eval(user.photos.sample.image_data)[:small][:id]
    !! #<NoMethodError: undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass>
    >> eval(user.photos.sample.image_data)[:small][:id]
    => "photo/47/image/small-2cd0928d02826f0614086a01ee97ef32.jpg"
    >> eval(user.photos.sample.image_data)[:small][:id]
    !! #<NoMethodError: undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass>
    >> eval(user.photos.sample.image_data)[:small][:id]
    !! #<NoMethodError: undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass>
    >> eval(user.photos.sample.image_data)[:small][:id]
    => "photo/47/image/small-2cd0928d02826f0614086a01ee97ef32.jpg"
    >> 
    => nil
    >> eval(user.photos.sample.image_data)[:small][:id]
    => "photo/47/image/small-2cd0928d02826f0614086a01ee97ef32.jpg"
    >> eval(user.photos.sample.image_data)[:small][:id]
    => "photo/47/image/small-2cd0928d02826f0614086a01ee97ef32.jpg"
    >> eval(user.photos.sample.image_data)[:small][:id]
    => "photo/47/image/small-2cd0928d02826f0614086a01ee97ef32.jpg"
    >> eval(user.photos.sample.image_data)[:small][:id]
    !! #<NoMethodError: undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass>
    >> user.photos.sample.image_data
    => "{\"original\":{\"id\":\"photo/47/image/original-114c9db755b25afe0398f5b25aed5bef.jpg\",\"storage\":\"store\",\"metadata\":{\"size\":61357,\"filename\":\"London-Escort-Angelina (5).jpg\",\"mime_type\":\"image/jpeg\",\"width\":500,\"height\":500}},\"large\":{\"id\":\"photo/47/image/large-c3985d412ee05495594caa659feca371.jpg\",\"storage\":\"store\",\"metadata\":{\"filename\":\"shrine-s320170627-29702-17km6c5.jpg\",\"size\":61356,\"mime_type\":\"image/jpeg\",\"width\":500,\"height\":500}},\"small\":{\"id\":\"photo/47/image/small-2cd0928d02826f0614086a01ee97ef32.jpg\",\"storage\":\"store\",\"metadata\":{\"filename\":\"shrine-s320170627-29702-ouo63f.jpg\",\"size\":25642,\"mime_type\":\"image/jpeg\",\"width\":300,\"height\":300}}}"
    >> user.photos.sample.image_data[:small]
    !! #<TypeError: no implicit conversion of Symbol into Integer>
    >> eval(user.photos.sample.image_data)[:small]
    => {:id=>"photo/47/image/small-2cd0928d02826f0614086a01ee97ef32.jpg", :storage=>"store", :metadata=>{:filename=>"shrine-s320170627-29702-ouo63f.jpg", :size=>25642, :mime_type=>"image/jpeg", :width=>300, :height=>300}}
    >> eval(user.photos.sample.image_data)[:small][:id]
    => "photo/47/image/small-2cd0928d02826f0614086a01ee97ef32.jpg"
    >> eval(user.photos.sample.image_data)[:small][:id]
    !! #<NoMethodError: undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass>
```

Any help is much appreciated!!!

Answer (score 0):

Your results are different because you use [sample](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-sample) method, whitch choose a random element from `user.photos`.

For prevent `undefined method [] for nil:NilClass` error you can use [&.dig](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Hash.html#method-i-dig) for ruby >= 2.3 or `try` if less

> nil&.dig(:small, :id)
>
> => nil
>
> nil.try(:dig, :small, :id)
>
> => nil

Comment: Please point out which version of Ruby introduced the `&.` syntax since it's quite new.

Comment: Hi Sergey, thanks for the input. I might be a bit slow here - how exactly do I apply "dig" here? I am not familiar with it. I run a few tests in the console. I new simply get "nil" all the time. >> eval(user.photos.sample.image_data).try(:dig, :small, :id)
=> nil

Comment: Is there a link to a reference to dig so I can read up on it?

Comment: Link added . Dig prevent you from errors like [] for nil. You have nil because your compact method get photo with blank image_data. Your data looks like json, if it is json, you don't need eval but JSON.parse. You can user.photos.map{|photo| photo.image_data.present? ?
 JSON.parse(photo.image_data) : photo.image_data)} . It returns to you array of parsed image_data.

Comment: Right, got it and thanked you for the input. Helpful to know about dig. It doesn't solve this particular issue, however. As it only starts working properly once I reindex the user index (ES). I tried to reindex only the particular document in question. However, that doesn't change anything.

Answer (score 0):

So, I could resolve the issue (workaround-ish) by reindexing the updated user document when a photo is uploaded or deleted. Forgot about the destroy part before. It doesn't seem right as it is messy given an entire record must be removed in ES and reindexed, but traffic is low and for the time being it works. If I figure out the issue, I will revert to this thread.